# What am I doing wrong that my index file will not render properly as a github page?

Tags: github

I'm trying to use GitHub as required of my class to launch a website.  Unfortunately, I have to be doing something wrong.  My filepaths in the index.html file are as follows:

link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"
for the style sheet

Now for the image I'm wanting to use I'm using:

img src="/images/TomEdwards.jpg" alt="Tom Edwards"

and I'm getting this instead at this location:
https://ladywebdevelop.github.io/bioSite/index.html

my file tree looks like this:
css (Folder)
images  (Folder)
README.md
index.html

What are my possible solutions, please?

I've tried several different ways in the file path names to access both the stylesheet and the images.

I'm expecting the stylesheet to render correctly with a colored background and the image to appear on the right-hand side under the horizontal navigation list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the stylesheet by changing this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

To this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

The stylesheet must be referenced correctly relative to the index file.

As for the image, I don't see it in the application's sources. Are you sure that it's committed to the repository, and located in the right place? The current codes has it here, which looks like a typo:

```html
<img src="TomEdwards/TomEdwards.jpg" alt="Tom Edwards">
```